# How to match a string from N-th field in a line using regex?

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I am trying to match string "RAV" on every line  on 15th word. Each word is delimited by "|" (pipe). I need to compare if line has this string or not. If yes, I will proceed with my next step.

I was trying this

```
((((?:[^|]*\|){17}(.*?)\|)+\|[^|]*$)|[^|]+(?=(\,\H\,))|(^([0-9]){4})|(([RAV]){3}))
```

But this one matches even if I have "RAV" first, second or any other fields. I need to match exactly on 15th field.

Comment: That regex looks weird. You have piles of other stuff there than just the part you're asking about, which is a bit confusing. As for that, `(?:[^|]*\|){17}` looks like it matches 17 fields terminated with pipes (iterated), but there's nothing in the other parts of the alternation to count fields. I'm not sure what it is you're doing there, but I wonder if that could be better done in separate parts instead of one big regex

Comment: This would appear to be a classic case of [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Answer (score 5):

You would not necessarily use a regular expression.

With `awk`:

```bash
awk -F '|' '$15 == "RAV" { print }' myfile
```

This would print each line from the file `myfile` whose 15th `|`-delimited field is exactly the string `RAV`.  This uses a string comparison, not a regular expression matching.

To match `RAV` as a sub-string anywhere in the 15th field, use

```bash
awk -F '|' '$15 ~ /RAV/ { print }' myfile
```

This uses `RAV` as an extended regular expression and matches it against the data in the 15th `|`-delimited field. If there is a match, the current line is printed.

If this is part of some script or program written in a language from which it is cumbersome to call `awk` (i.e. anything but a shell script), then split the string on the `|` delimiters and pick out the 15th element and do your comparison.

Using `awk` as a pseudo-code language, that could look something like

```c
nf = split($0, a, "|")
if (nf < 15)
    print "Not enough fields!" >"/dev/stderr"
else {
    if (a[15] == "RAV") print
}
```

Or, in Perl (without error check this time),

```perl
my @a = split /\|/, $string;
if ($a[15] eq "RAV") {
    print $string
}
```

In each variation above (including the initial `awk` commands), `print` stands in for whatever operation you need to perform to the data once you have determined that the 15th field matches `RAV`.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -E '^([^|]*\|){14}[^|]*RAV' infile
```

- `(...)` is known as group-match;
- `{N}` is known as fixed interval quantifier;
- `(...){N}` matches its group-match N times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression, but, uh. Yeah. About that. You probably want to instead do a field split with `awk` or such. Can you see why?

```
$ cat input
ok|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|RAV
ok|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|RAV|bar
bad|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|NOPE
bad|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|NOPE|bar
$ sed -E -n '/^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|RAV(\||$)/p' input
ok|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|RAV
ok|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|RAV|bar
```

The `[^|]*\|` form basically means "match a field" on the assumption that `|` cannot ever be escaped within a field and that gets repeated (I used `vi` to type it out via `14i`) fourteen times, and then you handle the 15th field. Pretty yucky and rather unmaintainable.

P.S. use `awk` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -ne '.put if / ^ [ .+ ]**14 % "|" RAV /;'
```

Nice answers above, however Raku has new, nifty `%` and `%%` modified quantifiers, which greatly simplifies this type of problem. According to the docs: *"To more easily match things like comma separated values, you can tack on a `%` modifier to any of the above quantifiers to specify a separator that must occur between each of the matches."* The `%%` modified quantifier allows trailing separators, like a trailing comma.

The code above with the `[ .+ ]` atom demands that each column has one-or-more characters (including whitespace). This could be changed to `[ \S+ ]` (one-or-more non-whitespace characters), or even `[ .* ]` (zero-or-more characters).

Also, similar to other answers you could approach this problem by splitting on `|` vertical bar:

```
raku -ne '.put if .split("|")[14] eq "RAV" // next;'  

#OR

raku -ne '.split("|")[14] eq "RAV" ?? $_.put !! next;'
```

Sample Input (thanks to @thrig):

```
ok|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|RAV
ok|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|RAV|bar
bad|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|NOPE
bad|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|NOPE|bar
```

Sample Output:

```
ok|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|RAV
ok|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|RAV|bar
```

https://raku.org